# regular expression in R for word of variable length between two characters

Tags: regex, r, gsub

How do I extract the word, wordofvariablelength from the string below.

```
<a href=\"http://www.adrive.com/browse/wordofvariablelength\" class=\"next-button\" id=\"explore-gutter\" data-linkid=\"huiazc\"> <strong class=\"text gutter-text \">
```

I was able to get the first part of the string using the below code, but is there a regular expression I can use to get only the word immediately after "browse/" and before "\", which here is the word, "wordofvariablelength" using the code below

```
mystring = substr(mystring,nchar("<a href=\"http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/")+1,nchar("<a href=\"http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/")+20)
```

Note that the word, wordofvariablelength could be of any length, and so I cannot hardcode and start and end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through regmatches function.

```
> x <- "<a href=\"http://www.adrive.com/browse/wordofvariablelength\" class=\"next-button\" id=\"explore-gutter\" data-linkid=\"huiazc\"> <strong class=\"text gutter-text \">"
> regmatches(x, regexpr('.*?"[^"]*/\\K[^/"]*(?=")', x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "wordofvariablelength"
```

**OR**

```
> regmatches(x, regexpr('[^/"]*(?="\\s+class=")', x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "wordofvariablelength"
```

**OR**

Much more simpler one using gsub.

```
> gsub('.*/|".*', "", x)
[1] "wordofvariablelength"
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answers about regexes. Do you know about a good tutorial on regexes? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, i learned regex from this site only . This http://www.regular-expressions.info/ covers all the regex flavours and use this https://regex101.com site for doing practical sessions . If you have any doubts in regex , feel free to ask me..

Comment: Thank you @AvinashRaj. I could not vote up your answer since I don't have 15 reputations.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sub('.*?\\.com/[^/]*\\/([a-z]+).*', '\\1', mystring)
#[1] "wordofvariablelength"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
 str_extract(mystring, perl('(?<=browse/)[A-Za-z]+'))
#[1] "wordofvariablelength"
```

#### data

```
mystring <- "<a href=\"http://www.adrive.com/browse/wordofvariablelength\" class=\"next-button\" id=\"explore-gutter\" data-linkid=\"huiazc\"> <strong class=\"text gutter-text \">"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex

```
/browse\/(.*?)\\/g
```

demo here https://regex101.com/r/gX4dC0/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex `(?<=browse/).*?(?=\\")`.
The regex means: check if we have `browse/`, then take all the subsequent characters up to (but without consuming) `\`.

Sample code (and a [sample program here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ1JhWWxFWWJkbU0)):

```
mystr <- "<a href=\"http://www.adrive.com/browse/wordofvariablelength\" class=\"next-button\" id=\"explore-gutter\" data-linkid=\"huiazc\"> <strong class=\"text gutter-text \">"
regmatches(mystr, regexpr('(?<=browse/).*?(?=\\")', mystr, perl=T))
```

`perl=T` means we are using *Perl*-like regex flavor that allows using fixed-width look-behind (`(?<=browse/)`).

Output:

```
[1] "wordofvariablelength"
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you found my regex/post useful, please consider upvoting, you can do it now :)

Comment: sure I just got enought points(15) to upvote an answer. thanks once again :)